# Why new answers appear before old answers?

Tags: discussion

Let's suppose that I answer a question, and my answer is correct. A little bit later, another guy post an answer, practically identical as mine, and his answer appears before than mine.

Although the time displayed tells that my answer was posted first, the OP could easily think that the first answer was posted first, and mark it as the correct.

Probably there is a reason for this, which I don't know. So, I am asking this question. Why new answers appear before old answers?

Comment: Sorry, I searched for this question, but I didn't find. You are right, it is a duplicate. Thank you